# App shows ads even after restricted background data

Tags: mobile-data, background-data

I restricted background data for my [file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) app. But still when I open the app, I am getting ads at the bottom.

How is that even possible? How the app able to connect to mobile data?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think the background data setting is working the way you believe it does. When you're using the app and it's in the foreground that setting has no effect (it's not *background* data), thus allowing it to serve ads. See [How does "Restrict background data" work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55831)

Comment: @eldarerathis thanks now I tested with the dolphin browser and it seem to connect internet with background data restricted. But I cant understand why I cant do the same with the google play? When I restrict for google play it asks for enabling it. But I am running google play as foreground app

Comment: That's actually something I've asked myself a couple of times: Why does *Play* require *background data* enabled when running in *foreground*? Definitely worth being asked as a separate question – though we already have [several questions *touching*  the issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+play+background+data), I couldn't see it explicitly "nailed" on a quick view. // Ooops: See [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28124/16575) for an explanation :)